# Geometry coordinates of USA state via CloudMade

Tags: geocoding, cloudmade

I need to get geometry coordinates of the USA states.
I use CloudMade API and it works well for the most states, but for several others I can't find coordinates - CouldMade API returns multiple results for other places, not states.

I use the requests like this one:
http://geocoding.cloudmade.com/e485574f2cf2424aac17f42908aa2ce3/geocoding/v2/find.js?query=HAWAII&return_geometry=true

Here is the list of states which couldn't be processed well.

```
CONNECTICUT
GEORGIA
HAWAII
FLORIDA
LOUISIANA
MARYLAND
MISSISSIPPI
NEW JERSEY
NORTH CAROLINA
NORTH DAKOTA
SOUTH CAROLINA
SOUTH DAKOTA
```

Does anybody know, is it possible to get the geo coordinates of these states using CouldMade service or any other geocoding services?

Answer (score 1):

Question is solved. Here is the correct request format (query parameter should contains 'county' prefix):

http://geocoding.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/geocoding/v2/find.js?return_location=true&results=10&skip=0&query=county:CONNECTICUT&return_geometry=true